# Lifting scheme vs traditional DWT

Tags: matlab, wavelet, wavelet-transform

I know that lifting scheme is an algorithm to compute the DWT by predicating and updating even and odd elements of the input signal, and as I think that it is should give the same results with the same wavelet family, and that what happened when I try the following code in MatLab with db1

```
lshaar = liftwave('db1');
[cA1,cD1] = lwt(x,lshaar);
[cA2,cD2] = dwt(x,'db1');
```

regardless the length of the input, but when I use db4, I obtained completely different answer.

can anyone help me, why this happened with db4 and higher order family.